# Styled component in HOC

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I want to add styles to my component wrapper using higher order component. Typescript says there is error with `ComponentWithAdddedColors`.

```
type Props = {
  bg?: string;
};

function withColors<TProps>(
  Component: React.ComponentType<TProps>
): React.ComponentType<TProps & Props> {

  const ColoredComponent: React.ComponentType<TProps & Props> = props => {
    const { bg, ...componentProps } = props;

    const ComponentWithAdddedColors = styled(Component)`
      ${bg && `background: ${bg};`}
    `;

    return <ComponentWithAdddedColors {...componentProps} />; //Typecheck error
  };

  return ColoredComponent;
}
```

When I want to return Component that was passed to HOC with `{...componentProps}` there is also typecheck error.

```
...
{
  const ColoredComponent: React.ComponentType<TProps & Props> = props => {
    const { bg, ...componentProps } = props;

    return <Component {...componentProps} />; //Typecheck error
  };

  return ColoredComponent;
}
```

But, when I pass everything to Component with `{...props}` there is not typecheck error.

```
...
{
  const ColoredComponent: React.ComponentType<TProps & Props> = props => {
    return <Component {...props} />; //No error
  };

  return ColoredComponent;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the type error that you get?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/uzMmexdf

Comment: Why don't you prefer theming support in styled-components? https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#theming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
export function withColors<T>(Component: React.ComponentType<T>) {
    return styled(Component)<Props>`
        ${({ bg }) => bg && `background: ${bg};`}
    `
}

const Foo: React.FC<{ bar: string }> = props => <div>{props.bar}</div>
const ColoredFoo = withColors(Foo)
export const redFoo = <ColoredFoo bg="red" bar="baz" />
```

If you wanted to lock-in your colors and not expose the color props, however, then I'm afraid you might have exposed a TypeScript bug. I can't seem to get around it myself (without using `additionalProps as any`); however, I did approach it a bit differently.

```
function withColors<T>(Component: React.ComponentType<T>, additionalProps: Props) {
    const { bg } = additionalProps;
    const ComponentWithAddedColors = styled(Component)<Props>`
        ${bg && `background: ${bg};`}
    `
    const result: React.FC<T> = props => (
        <ComponentWithAddedColors {...props} {...(additionalProps as any)} />
    )
    return result
}

export const RedFoo = withColors(Foo, { bg: 'red' })
```