# Extend HOC props with styled-components types

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I'm trying to wrap styled-components in HOCs and extend the base prop types. I would expect the following example to work, but I'm getting TS errors `Property 'active' does not exist on type...`

```js
interface CustomCardProps {
  active: boolean
}

export const CustomCard: React.FC<CardItem & typeof CustomCardStyle> = ({
  active,
  children,
  ...other
}) => (
  <CustomCardStyle active={active} {...other}>
    {active ? children : null}
  </CustomCardStyle>
)

const CustomCardStyle = styled(Card)<CustomCardProps>``
```

Being able to extend the styled-components' type directly would save me from importing the base props and would include missing types from the actual styled component, like `as`.

```js
export const CustomCard: React.FC<CardItem & CardProps & CustomCardProps>
```

Similar question: [Styled component in HOC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57355610/styled-component-in-hoc)